# Google backup and sync unable to sync a file

Tags: google-sync

I have been using Google Drive for about a year and the sync tool (now called Google Backup and Sync) has been working fine until now. I have a set of documents that I edit from two locations (work and home) and sync them before making any changes. Last night, the sync tool gave me this error:

> Can't sync 1 item                                                       (VIEW)

On clicking "view", it shows this message:

> An unknown error occured
>   Download error - /name/of/my/file

How should I resolve this problem? Is there a way of manually merging my changes?

(PS: The actual file is an encrypted document (not sure if this matters). I am using Windows 10 Home 64-bit v1607 with Backup and Sync version 3.3.6.6721.3394.)

Answer (score 1):

I get that error some times....try these workarounds to get rid of it:

- restart Google Backup
- rename the file
- move the file
- change the file (if possible)
- is the path too long? (shorten in)
- upload it via the web-interface

Answer (score 1):

Although this was asked a long time ago, here is another trick that has worked for me..
I have been using google backup and sync client to sync local backups to google drive service, and the failed upload issue was commonly present as well.
I am talking about filesizes varying from ~100-200MB up to 1.5GB.
After a lot of trial and error, it seems the only thing that "fixed" the problem for me was to set an upload limit a little bit less than what the DSL line can achieve. (eg. 1MBps upload line = set upload limit to ~70KB/sec on the google client..
Good luck!